# Event notation for exact events when "at least" events are given.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

The question I'm struggling with goes like this:

Over a 24-hour period, three types of routers receive different messages.

Let $A_i$ be the event where Router A receives **at least** *i* packet(s) during the day.

Let $B_i$ be the event where Router B receives **at least** *i* packet(s) during the day.

Let $C_i$ be the event where Router C receives **at least** *i* packet(s) during the day.

Using these events, express the following events:

1. Router B receives exactly 4 packets throughout the day.
2. No routers receive any packets throughout the day.

My solution:

1. $\bar{B_3} \cap B_4 \cap \bar{B_5}$
2. $A_0 \cap B_0 \cap C_0$

The bit that trips me up about these questions is the **at least** wording.

I know my solution for 1 can't be right, because essentially I'm saying that B can't receive at least 3, can receive at least 4, and can't receive at least 5, but there's nothing stopping that event from receiving 6 packets.

Similarly for 2, I'm saying that all the routers can receive at least 0 packets, but that obviously means that they can receive more than 0 too.

Comment: $B_4\cap \overline{B}_3=\phi$. Also $\overline{B}_3 \cap \{\mbox{B gets exactly 6}\}=\phi$.

Comment: Also, $A_0$ is the whole sample space!

Comment: That's a good point on the empty set relationships.  Perhaps $\bar{B_5} \cap B_3 = \emptyset$ for the first question?

And then $A_1 \cap B_1 \cap C_1 = \emptyset$ for the second?

Comment: $B_3=\{3,4,5,..\}$ and $B_3^c=\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Ah, true.  $B_5 \cap B_4^c = \emptyset$ should be it then.  Thanks so much!  If you put it in answer form I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know my solution for 1 can't be right, because essentially I'm saying that B can't receive at least 3, can receive at least 4, and can't receive at least 5, but there's nothing stopping that event from receiving 6 packets.

Your solution is not right, but not for that reason.

Note that the **complement** of "at least" is "lesser than".

So, yes, if the event claims it does not receive at least 5, you *are stopping* that event from containing 6 (or more).

No; what you *don't want* the event to claim is that it does not receive at least 3, since that says it receives lesser than 3.

You simply want to say "at least 4 but lesser than 5".

> Similarly for 2, I'm saying that all the routers can receive at least 0 packets, but that obviously means that they can receive more than 0 too.

Indeed, you want to say that each router *does not* receive more that zero.   Which is to say, each router receives *lesser than* one.

Comment: Hi Graham, so for the first one, something like this will do, right? $B_5 \cap B_4^c = \emptyset$.  The intersection of receiving at least 5 events and lesser than 4 events should be the empty set.  4 packets is the only value that can hold for that condition.

Comment: No. @Yvihs .  You want to represent the set of *favoured outcomes* for the router's packet count.  That is: The set which is "at least 4 and less than 5".

Comment: Hmm okay, so at least 4 and less than 5 would be represented as $B_4 \cap B_5^c$ right?  Because the intersection here would just be {4}.

Comment: And similarly for the second question.  $A_1^c \cap B_1^c \cap C_1^c$, which can only be {0}.

Comment: Indeed. @Yvihs .